# Custom left menu shape on WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm designing a WPF application, and I wanted it to have a customized left menu. Actually I would like the left menu to look like on the image:

[image]

I know this has something to do with overriding the template, but I'm not sure how to draw that shape. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well i don't know if this is what you want but try this code:

```
    <WrapPanel>
        <Rectangle Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Fill="Aqua"/>            
        <Border CornerRadius="0,100,100,0" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Background="Aqua"/>
    </WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Exactly that... I knew there should be an easy way using cornerradius... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this can be done by Combining shapes in WPF. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://keyvan.io/combine-shapes-in-windows-presentation-foundation).